# MPMoviePlayerController buffered time being lost when application is entering foreground

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am buffering a video which is in the m3u8 format and i am setting this url as the contenturl for MPMovieplayerController

I am running a background thread that runs every 0.3 seconds which i use to check the buffered and played duration and perform the check accordingly

```
if(!mPlaybackProgressTimer)
    mPlaybackProgressTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(didPlayback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
```

and in didplayback

..

```
- (void)didPlayback:(id)sender {

    NSTimeInterval totalDuration = [mVideoPlayerController duration];

    NSTimeInterval playbackTime = [mVideoPlayerController currentPlaybackTime];
    float playbackProgress = 0.0;

   if(playbackTime > 0.0 && totalDuration > 0.0)
       playbackProgress = playbackTime / totalDuration;

   mPercentWatched = round(100 * playbackProgress);

   NSTimeInterval bufferedTime = [mVideoPlayerController playableDuration];
   float bufferProgress = 0.0;

   if(playbackTime > 0.0 && totalDuration > 0.0)
       bufferProgress = bufferedTime / totalDuration;

   [self setProgress:bufferProgress forProgressType:eProgressTypeBuffer];
   [self setProgress:playbackProgress forProgressType:eProgressTypePlay];
}
```

The issue is that if i am pressing the home button and then coming back into the app the *bufferedtime* is being lost ie the data has to buffered once again .. 
Is there anyway to overcome this issue .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is by design an not in any way changeable.